# Adding array values from a text file and printing them

Tags: java, arrays

I've a text file named `new.txt` in my C drive, i'm trying to get the contents of this file using a java program into my multidimensional array using the below program.

```
package square;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Square {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[][] = new String[4][4];
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C://new.txt");
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(fr);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    a[i][j] = scanner.next();
                }
            }
            System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(a));
            scanner.close();
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Here when i'm trying to run this program, i'm getting the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at square.Square.main(Square.java:20)
```

when i'm changing `a[i][j] = scanner.next();` to `a[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();` and changing the array type to `int`m it is throwing the below Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at square.Square.main(Square.java:20)
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix it.

The content of my text file is.

```
#####
#####
#####
#####
…..
```

Comment: Is the content of your text file really `#` or digits? Please provide a real example.

Comment: well for starters change your for loop to `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {  for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {` or something similar using the array's dimensions.  Because right now that `< 5` will go out of bounds.

Comment: Hi @aioobe, this is the exact content i've in my textfile.

Comment: Hi @chancea, it s still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is simple. First look at your textfile:

```
#####
#####
#####
#####
…..
```

Here we have 5 tokens (4 x '#####' and 1 x '…..'). Take a look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html at the next() function.

```
NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

So after the scanner read the last token, that is '…..', there are no more tokens available.

Here my suggested solution:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Square {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[][] = new String[5][5];
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("new.txt");
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(fr);
            ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                l.add(scanner.next());
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
            {
                String toSplit = l.get(i);
                String[] splitted = toSplit.split("");
                for(int j = 0; j < splitted.length; ++j)
                {
                    a[i][j] = splitted[j];
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // test the result
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j)
            {
                System.out.println(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention: The last two lines are null, because the last token has 3 characters.
So a[4][3] and a[4][4] will be null.

Comment: Hi, This is awesome, works as expected, but can you please help me in doing this using arrays. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what you want exactly? Do you want a multidimensional array where every cell is a character?

Comment: Yes, this is how i want it

Answer (score 0):

The default delimiter is white space.Since you don't have any whitespace the first String read itself is #####\n#####\n#####\n#####.But there are a lot of other things like loop wrong in this problem.Can you try the below changes and see if it works for you.Otherwise please provide more explanation

```
String a[][] = new String[5][5];
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(fr).useDelimiter("");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; i++) {
       if(scanner.hasNext("\n"))
           scanner.next();
       a[i][j] = scanner.next();
      }

 System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(a));
        scanner.close();
```

Comment: I get `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at square.Square.main(Square.java:24)

`

Answer (score 0):

A shote note ahead:

Please check the two dimensions of your `String` array. Currently it is

```
new String[4][4];
```

and allows storing of 16 values (4x4). The code used in your loop looks like you expect more values. Hence I increased the array to

```
new String[5][5];
```

Now to a possible answer to your question:

To circumvent a fixed value of 5 in the outer `for`-loop I replaced it with a `while`-loop:

```
int i=0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  String[] separatedChars = line.split("(?!^)");
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    a[i][j] = separatedChars[j];
  }
  i++;
}
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(a));
scanner.close();
```

Instead of using only next in the inner `for`-loop I am using `scanner.nextLine()`to read a complete line and then split it up. The result is then used to fill the given array.
Output for four lines of 5x#

```
[[#, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #, #], [null, null, null, null, null]]s
```